# Add files upload to basic form AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, file, upload

I have a working Ajax form, now I'm trying to add file upload to it but it doesn't work. The file isn't uploaded or found in the `$_FILES` array. The code is pretty straight-forward so I don't know what I could be doing wrong. I'm giving the HTML, AJAX and PHP code here, but since the HTML and PHP are so simple, I think I must be missing something in the Ajax function since I don't have much experience with that. I can fetch all data from the form but not file.

In developer mode
[There is no business_docs data in parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RKwW.png)

**HTML CODE**

```
<form class="well form-horizontal" action="rejestracja/nowy" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="contact_form">
    <input name="user_email" placeholder="Adres E-mail" class="form-control"  type="text" required>
    <input name="user_phone" placeholder="" class="form-control" type="text">
    <input name="business_docs" placeholder="" class="form-control" type="file">
</form>
```

**AJAX CODE**

```
// Get the form instance
var $form = $(e.target);

// Get the BootstrapValidator instance
var bv = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');

// Use Ajax to submit form data
$.ajax({
    url: $form.attr('action'),
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,               
    data: $form.serialize(),
    dataType    : 'json'
})
```

**PHP CODE**

```
 if ( !isset($_POST['business_docs'])) 
 {
     $data['success'] = false;
     $errors['files_upload'] = 'Dodanie pliku nie powiodło się, spróbuj ponownie';
     $data['errors']  = $errors;                    
     echo json_encode($data);

     return false;

}

else
{
     move_uploaded_file($_POST['business_docs']['tmp_name'], '../../uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);

}
```

Comment: Instead of `data: $form.serialize()`, use `formdata`

Answer (score 0):

You used    `$_FILES['file']['name']` instead of `['business_docs']['name']` i hope it will work fine.